# Is $n$ always a strong probable prime to base $n - 1$?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primality-test

Here is the [Miller–Rabin extension to Fermat’s little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test):

> If $p$ is an odd prime and $p - 1 = 2^s d$ with $d$ odd, then for every $a$ coprime to $p$, either $a^d ≡ 1 \pmod p$ or there exists $r$ such that $0 ≤ r < s$ and $a^{2^r d} ≡ -1 \pmod p$.

When turning it into an algorithm, the [Miller–Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_test), Cormen et al. in their book *Introduction to Algorithms* choose $a$ randomly between $1$ and $n - 1$ inclusive.

It is pointless to test for $a = 1$ since it is coprime to $n$ and $a^d = 1^d = 1 ≡ 1 \pmod n$, that is **$n$ is always a strong probable prime to base $1$**. So we can optimise the algorithm by choosing $a$ randomly between $2$ and $n - 1$ inclusive.

But is it also pointless to test for $a = n - 1$? It is coprime to $n$ but does there always exist $r$ such that $0 ≤ r < s$ and $a^{2^r d} = (n - 1)^{2^r d} ≡ -1 \pmod n$, that is **is $n$ always a strong probable prime to base $n - 1$**? If that is the case, we can optimise the algorithm by choosing $a$ randomly between $2$ and $n - 2$ inclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, base $n - 1$ is also pointless because $d$ is odd, so we have

$$(n - 1)^d \equiv (-1)^d = -1 \pmod n.$$

Hence $n$ is always a strong Fermat pseudoprime to base $n - 1$.

Comment: I suppose that $(n - 1)^d ≡ (-1)^d \pmod n$ because $(n - 1)^d - (-1)^d = n \sum_{k=0}^{d - 1} (n - 1)^{d - 1 - k} (-1)^k = k’n$?

Comment: Why do you say that $n$ is a ‘strong pseudoprime’ to base $n - 1$ since by definition a [strong pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller–Rabin_primality_test#Strong_probable_primes) means it is actually *composite* but declared strong probable prime under the Miller–Rabin primality test? To me we can only state that $n$ is a strong probable prime to base $n - 1$, whereas $n$ can actually be either prime or composite, depending on its value.

Comment: The point is that every number is screened as prime, so this particular test is utterly useless. To call a number passing a test "pseudoprime" or "probable prime" (even in the case that it is actually prime) is usual practice although it might be the wrong terminology because of the definition of "pseudoprime". PARI/GP for example uses the command "ispseudoprime" and returns true in the case it is a prime.